# turn infinite loop into finite loop

Tags: infinite-loop, iteration

I am trying to make a table where I can save the stock value with the iterative part, where I should have 100 sequence with 843 entry in each sequence. 
The loop doesn't run correctly in the sense that it just says "running", so I am assuming it is running infinitely. I am referring to the for loop at the end, I have updated this post to include the background information I started with as seen in the code. My main goal is to get the matrix to iterate with respect to x values. For example matrix 1 should respond to the first row of x and matrix 2 should correspond with second row of x.

```
dt = 0.0001;
dxt = r*dWt;
r = .005;
t = .0833;
sigma = .2183;
S0 = 201.05;
k = 212.50;

X = Table[0.0158, 100, 834];
For[i = 1, i <= 100, i++, 
For[j = 2, j <= 834, j++, 
X[[i, j]] = 
X[[i, j - 1]] + r*RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, (dt)^1/2]];
];
];

\[Mu] = dt/2 dS;
\[Lambda] = (dt*sigma^2)/(2*sigma^2);
s = Range[0, 500, 5];(*Stock price*)
V = Table[0, 101]; 
(* value of option at particular time *)
For[i = 1, 
i <= 101, i++,
If[s[[i]] - k > 0,
V[[i]] = s[[i]] - k,
V[[i]] = 0
];
];

For[p = 1, p < Length[X], p++, 
For[q = 2, q <= 834, q++, 
btcs[p_, q_] = 
SparseArray[{{m_, m_} -> 
1 + 2*\[Lambda]*Indexed[s, m]^2 + 
Indexed[X, {p, q}]*dt, {m_, l_} /; 
l - m == 1 -> -\[Lambda]*Indexed[s, m]^2 - \[Mu]*
Indexed[X, {p, q}]*Indexed[s, m], {m_, l_} /; 
m - l == 1 -> -\[Lambda]*Indexed[s, m]^2 + \[Mu]*
Indexed[X, {p, q}]*Indexed[s, m]}, {101, 101}];
A = btcs[p_, q_]];];
Print[A]
```

But my code is infinitely running and not giving me an output.

Comment: The posted code doesn't do anything. `X` is undefined so `Length[X]` is `0` and the outer `For` test fails immediately.

Comment: I had X  from my previous part, where X = Table[0.0158, 100, 834].

Comment: I am trying to iterate where the loop will run through my R1C1, R1C2, R3C3...all the way up to R3C834 and then carry on with R2Ca and so on... that's is represented as 'p' and 'q'. my 'm' and 'l' are just indices for specific position within matrix.

Comment: Then edit your question to include all required information.

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

nrows = 100;
ncols = 834;
```

**Note that `dWt` is undefined**

```
dt = 0.0001;
dxt = r*dWt;
r = .005;
t = .0833;
sigma = .2183;
S0 = 201.05;
k = 212.50;

X = ConstantArray[0.0158, {nrows, ncols}];

SeedRandom[1234] 
(* required to make results reproducible *)
```

**I assumed that `(dt)^1/2`  was intended to be `dt^(1/2)`, i.e., `Sqrt[dt]`**

```
Table[X[[i, j]] = X[[i, j - 1]] +
    r*RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, Sqrt[dt]]],
  {i, nrows}, {j, 2, ncols}];
```

**Note that `dS` is undefined**

```
μ = dt/2 dS;
λ = (dt*sigma^2)/(2*sigma^2);
s = Range[0, 500, 5];
(*Stock price*)
```

Definition of `V` can be simplified to

```
V = Clip[s - k, {0, 500}];
```

Population of the sparse array is slow but does complete

```
(For[p = 1, p < nrows, p++, 
    For[q = 2, q <= ncols, q++, 
      btcs[p_, q_] = 
       SparseArray[{{m_, m_} -> 
          1 + 2*λ*Indexed[s, m]^2 + Indexed[X, {p, q}]*dt, {m_, l_} /;
            l - m == 1 -> -λ*Indexed[s, m]^2 - μ*
            Indexed[X, {p, q}]*Indexed[s, m], {m_, l_} /; 
           m - l == 1 -> -λ*Indexed[s, m]^2 + μ*
            Indexed[X, {p, q}]*Indexed[s, m]}, {nrows + 1, nrows + 1}];
      A = btcs[p_, q_]];];) // AbsoluteTiming

(* {286.008, Null} *)
```

Looking at the second row (**Note again that `dS` was not defined**):

```
Normal[A][[2]]

(* {-0.00125 + 4.60593*10^-6 dS, 1.0025, -0.00125 - 
  4.60593*10^-6 dS, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, \
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, \
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, \
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
  0} *)

% // Length

(* 101 *)
```